# Salto de linea C++

Tags: c++

intento hacer un programa para la Universidad pero no me detecta los saltos de linea, así que hice otro de prueba simple para probarlo y tampoco me lo detecta, y intenté utilizar '\n' y '\r\n' pero ninguno funciona, si algúno sabe que podría ser se lo agradecería mucho!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
  char letra;
  fstream fe("prueba.txt");
        if(fe.is_open()){
            while(!fe.eof()){
                fe>>letra;
                cout<<letra;    
                    if(letra=='\n'){
                        cout<<"Salto";
                    }
            }

            fe.close(); 
        }else{
            cout<<"No existe";
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tu problema es que [`std::basic_istream::operator>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt) es un *extractor de datos con formato*; eso implica que ciertas *secuencias de bytes* son **usadas internamente por la librería**, y **nunca llegarán a tí**. Entre ellas, como ya has descubierto, está el carácter `'\n'`.

Para *saltarse* ese inconveniente, tenemos la función [`std::basic_istream::get( )`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get); esta realiza una lectura *en bruto*, sin utilizar ningún dato para sí. **Esta es** la función que debes usar:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main( ) {
  char letra;
  fstream fe( "prueba.txt" );

  if( fe.is_open( ) ) {
    while( !fe.eof( ) ) {
      fe.get( letra );
      cout << letra;    

      if( letra == '\n' ) {
        cout << "Salto";
      }
    }

    fe.close( );
  } else {
    cout << "No existe";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estaba a punto de enviar la respuesta :'(

Comment: jejeje ... ¡ No puedes ganar contra el *madrugator* oficial del sitio ! ;-p

Comment: Me han faltado 5 segundos... verás a la próxima :P