# Contar saltos de linea de un .txt en C++

Tags: c++

Estoy intentando contar los saltos de linea que hay en un archivo .txt pero no me funciona, quizas se deba hacer de una forma especifica. Mi funcion es esta:

```
int Texto::contarSaltosLinea() {
    int contSaltosLinea = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < getTamanioTexto(); i++) {
        if (texto[i] == '\n') {
            contSaltosLinea++;
        }
    }
    return contSaltosLinea;
}
```

Comment: puedes contar el número de líneas que hay en tu archivo txt, cada línea que haya es por un salto de línea. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/390085/c%C3%B3mo-contar-l%C3%ADneas-de-un-archivo-en-c

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no entiendo muy bien el codigo (no esta explicado del todo) y al usar char es un poco distinto y no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Salto de linea C++](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/244540/salto-de-linea-c). Sino, edita la pregunta con un [ejemplo mínimo verificable](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Mateo olvidé mencionar que debo usar string. Al usar char es un poco distinto y me tira errores de compatibilidad, intenté usar ese código pero en lugar de "letra" usé "string[0]" y asi para acceder a cada caracter y la verdad no me funciona.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que falla? ¿Qué obtienes y qué esperabas obtener?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster en mi codigo obtengo el resultado 0 y espero obtener cuantos \n o saltos de linea hay en un txt. En el codigo que me comentaron me falla por la conversion char, y yo necesito hacerlo tipo string. Osea si funciona con char pero hay funciones que como parametro reciben si o si un char

Comment: No hay ninguna *conversión a `char`* en tu código. Salvo que la conversión esté en algún punto del código que no muestras. ¿Por qué no compartes cómo rellenas la variable `texto` y el contenido de la función `getTamanioTexto`?